# Nuget Error NU3037,NU3028 When publishing container

Tags: visual-studio, nuget-package

We are facing the following errors when publishing a container to Fargate from visual studio. the solution was all working fine till this evening.

... docker build: from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature's timestamp found a chain building issue: UntrustedRoot: self signed certificate in certificate chain
... docker build:  : error NU3037: Package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions 2.1.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature validity period has expired.
... docker build: : error NU3028: Package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions 2.1.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository countersignature's timestamp found a chain building issue: UntrustedRoot: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Answer (score 1):

This issue is due to the certificates expiring, You can find the issue created for this on Github

1. [Github issue 10492](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/10492)
2. [Github issue 10491](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/10491)

The Microsoft certificates were expiring on Jan, 2021 which has caused this issue. For more information please read this article [Microsoft author signing certificate update](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/microsoft-author-signing-certificate-update/)