# I think I understand the NU3037 and NU3028 Error that I'm getting in GitHub, but how do I fix it?

Tags: github, webassembly, uno

It appears that the cause of my error is: [Nuget Error NU3037,NU3028 When publishing container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65921546/nuget-error-nu3037-nu3028-when-publishing-container), but I can't figure out how to fix it.  I have not been able to find a NuGet.config file in my project repository, add the new Microsoft certificate:

> AA12DA22A49BCE7D5C1AE64CC1F3D892F150DA76140F210ABD2CBFFCA2C18A27
> nor can I find anywhere in my GitHub repository that allows me to modify a NuGetClient Policy.

I have looked at this on and off for 6 months and now need to post a new build.
This is a sample of the error message from my Build and Deploy Job.

```
/home/runner/work/PhotoViewer/PhotoViewer/UnoPhotoViewer/UnoPhotoViewer.Wasm/UnoPhotoViewer.Wasm.csproj : error NU3028: Package 'System.Linq 4.3.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository primary signature's timestamp found a chain building issue: UntrustedRoot: self signed certificate in certificate chain
/home/runner/work/PhotoViewer/PhotoViewer/UnoPhotoViewer/UnoPhotoViewer.Wasm/UnoPhotoViewer.Wasm.csproj : error NU3037: Package 'System.Linq 4.3.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository primary signature validity period has expired.
```

The code works, the build and runs on the desktop, it only fails in the GitHub build.